# How do I scrape a text in nested span using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following html code:

`< div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="line">< span class="html-tag"> &lt;Value&gt; </span>< span class="text"> 14966.50</span> < span class="html-tag" >&lt;/Value&gt;< /span ></div>`

How do I extract `14966.50`?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I'm just a beginner. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('Your URL')
raw = req.text

html = BeautifulSoup(raw, 'html.parser')

infos = html.select('Value')
print(infos[0])
```

Comment: How to get rid of the junk? <value>14966.50</value>

Comment: Just write as infos.text

Comment: I have an answer like this in panda: 
0  [[[15470.90], \n], \n, [[15400.30], \n], \n, [...
1  [[[15928.80], \n], \n, [[15094.90], \n], \n, [...
2  [[[16077.00], \n], \n, [[15468.00], \n], \n, [...
How can I get rid of those junk?

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML tags are just as messy as you put them, I suggest you use this library to deal with them.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="line">
  <span class="html-tag">
    <Value>
      <span class="text"> 14966.50 <span class="html-tag">
    </Value>
      </span>
</div>
'''

doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
text = doc.Value.text
print (text)
```

Result：

```
14966.50
```

You can also get a div first, then Value.

```
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
text = doc.select('div.line>Value>text()')
print (text)
```

Here's an example of SimplifiedDoc: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples